# How to build third party API's using grape gem and jwt as authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authentication, jwt, ruby-grape

I have an web app with api's built for android and ios apps. With `JWT` token for authentication.

Now I want to build `third party api's` for my app clients to integrate apis into there websites.

I integrated [`Grape`](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape) gem, `grape-swagger` for building api's.
As I'm already using JWT for native app api's. I'm trying to use same authentication for third party apis.

I'm assuming it is safe to use JWT for api's but still I'm asking. Is it safe to use JWT for third party api's because client could expose his token?

I need some references/links on how to building third party apis using jwt as authentication and grape.

**How do I proceed with jwt authentication and grape**

- Shall I give client a page in the website to add custom secret key for encryption then generate token with user.id and email as payload, so that he can validate signature on his end. And ask client to send this token for all future requests.
- Shall I create `/users/sign_in` api and when user sends username password. Shall I send jwt token with 24 hours expiration and ask client to generate new token for every 24 hours.

Is there any other way I can do authentication

Answer (score 0):

I use JWT for authentication using my own scheme using Authorization: header as well as for whole communication between client and server. The Grape::API handler begins with:

```
content_type    :jwt, 'application/jwt'
formatter       :jwt, Rack::JWTFormatter
parser          :jwt, Rack::JWTParser
format          :jwt
```

Errors are formatted with `error_formatter` and if recepient is unknown (i.e. "iss" claim not found), it is returned without signing/encrypting using `JWT.encode(data, nil, 'none')`

How to implement formatter and parser is described in [Grape Documentation](http://intridea.github.io/grape/docs/index.html#API_Data_Formats).